# Check CPU and other hardware components in Lubuntu

Tags: cpu, overheating, temperature

Tell me please which are the best ways to check the temperature of the CPU and other hardware components in Lubuntu?

It would be better if the applications could even tell me which are the normal average temperatures or temperatures in which should fit my hardware configuration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**lm-sensors**](http://www.lm-sensors.org/)

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

Then run:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

finsish the requests then run the command

```
sensors
```

Sample output:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +59°C  (high =  +100°C)
coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 1:      +59°C  (high =  +100°C)
coretemp-isa-0002
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 2:      +55°C  (high =  +100°C)
coretemp-isa-0003
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 3:      +56°C  (high =  +100°C)
```

Check [this source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-get-sensors-information/) for more information

Comment: @Mathux  Tell me please do you think that these temperatures are too high ?                                                                        sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)
temp2:        +29.2°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp3:        +75.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)
temp4:        +72.0°C  (crit = +256.0°C)
temp5:        +68.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +74.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +75.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

Comment: @XPDIN Then you got your answer? What is the problem?

Comment: @XPDIN With respect to you result it looks ok you should take care when your temp reach the crit: critical temp

Comment: Thanks @Maythux, now I hope is ok, it was a misunderstanding, now I can't give you more than 2 points until you will not edit your answer. I hope that the green check is ok now....

Answer (score 3):

you could try Psensor, you can download it in the Ubuntu software center. It gives you a desktop app which shows you the temperature of te cores, cpu, cpu load and the bridge temperatures.

it also enables you to set warnings for certain temperatures.

Comment: in my experience psensor is simply better than lm-sensors. I believe it's actually just a configuration script + GUI frontend for lm-sensors, but nonetheless it actually works, whereas I have had numerous issues getting lm-sensors to detect anything useful, and I don't have time to go figure it all out.

as for seeing this from the command line, I usually use **byobu** or, even better, **inxi -Fx** (that's *inxi* with the *-Fx* switch).